# Finding Game Object with Regular Expressions

Tags: unity, c#

Is there a way to use a Regular expression in the GameObject.Find() method?

I'm making a checkers game and I've got pieces named Red Piece (x,y) and White Piece (x,y) (where x & y are actual integer coordinates). I want to destroy a piece at a certain x,y. So what I'm trying to do is something like

```
Destroy(GameObject.Find(Regex.Matches("(Red)|(White) Piece (" + x + ","+ y + ")")));
```

I need it to find any object with a name that contains "Piece (x,y)" whether it's a red piece or a white piece, and destroy it. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I suggest you make a minigame by following one of the great tutorials available. This will drastically help you in much less time than trying to learn the basics on your own.

Answer (score 3):

**No, not using [`GameObject.Find`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html).**

You could, maintain your own list of object names, and search that using [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013461/how-to-filter-a-list-of-strings-matching-a-pattern). Then pass the found string into `GameObject.Find` to get the actual game object from the name.

However, I'm not really clear on why you're naming checkers pieces to include their location (since checkers [pieces move](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkers#Rules)). But you can find game objects at a specific location, using something like a [raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html). But I'd recommend simply reorganizing the way you manage objects. There are a few ways to do that. Maintain a 2D array that contains references to all the gameobjects for the pieces. Or keep better information about how you're moving pieces, to include the spaces they're "jumping".

Answer (score 2):

`Find` cannot do this. You could try using [`FindObjectsOfType`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) to get an array of `GameObject`s, and then manually filter that list by rejecting any with a name that doesn't match your pattern.

However, it seems like you could be solving the issue at a higher level. For example, if you're just trying to remove all "piece" game objects from the world, leaving behind any other game objects you're using for other things, you could consider:

- tagging each of those objects when you *create* them (or otherwise perform the manipulation on them that gets them ready to be deleted), and then using `FindObjectsWithTag`
- similarly, put them into a `List<GameObject>` called `pieces` (or something) so that you can find them all later to destroy them.

The last option is potentially far, far more efficient than having to traverse *every* game object in the world and perform a regex, or even just a substring comparison, against them.